# If $G = \{ A \in GL(3,\mathbb R): A\vec{x} = \vec{x} \}$ where $\vec{x}\in \mathbb R^3$, show $G$ is a subgroup of $GL(3,\mathbb R)$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory

If $G = \{ A \in GL(3,\mathbb R): A\vec{x} = \vec{x} \}$ where $\vec{x}\in \mathbb R^3$, show $G$ is a subgroup of $GL(3,\mathbb R)$.

I know I have to show closure and the fact that inverse exists in $G$, but I'm having trouble showing this formally.

Comment: Omitting arrows in $\vec{x}$ is a good idea. You did this partly in your attempt. Try to unify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A^{-1}A= id$ therefore  $A^{-1}A(x)= x = A^{-1}(A(x)) = A^{-1}(x)$.

Comment: Thank you. Also, is my method for showing closure correct?

Comment: $(A-I)x(B-I)x$ I'm not sure what you meant by this, since is seems your are multiplying elements of $\mathbb{R}^3$. You could just use that  matrix multiplication is associative. $AB(x)= A(B(x))=A(x)=x$